# Using dplyr rename_ when both new name and name to replace are variables

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, tidyverse

I have a `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(id = LETTERS[1:5], val = 1:5)
```

And I'd like to rename the `"id"` column name to `"new.id"` using `dplyr` `rename_`.

```
from.name <- "id"
to.name <- "new.id"
```

Trying:

```
df %>% dplyr::rename_(.dots = c(to.name = from.name))
```

changes `"id"` to `"to.name"`

Trying:

```
df %>% dplyr::rename_(.dots = c("to.name = from.name"))
```

give the error:

```
Error: All arguments must be named
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

And so does:

```
df %>% dplyr::rename_(.dots = c("to.name = 'from.name'"))
```

Any idea what's the correct usage?

Comment: I'm curious: Is there a reason why you [keep using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640769/using-tidyrs-gather) the deprecated `dplyr` (or `tidyr` as for your earlier question) verbs.

Comment: From the linked post: `df %>% rename_(.dots = setNames(from.name, to.name))` works.

Comment: Just out of date.